How to import and run a Python project in an IDE (VSCode) that refers to modules?
I am learning Python and wanted to run one of Cormen's textbook examples that are in Python.
I downloaded Python.zip from https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262046305/introduction-to-algorithms/ Resources tab.
I extracted it and it is a number of folders, one per chapter.
I do not see an "import project" option in VSC.
Trying to run randomized_select.py from Chapter 9 folder in the debugger, I get error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'randomized_quicksort'

It is coming from
from randomized_quicksort import randomized_partition

File c:\Users\Me\Documents\Learn\MS-CS\Foundations of Data Structures and Algorithms\CLRS_Python\Chapter 9\randomized_select.py:33
      1 #!/usr/bin/env python3
      2 # randomized_select.py
      3 
   (...)
     30 #                                                                       #
     31 #########################################################################
---> 33 from randomized_quicksort import randomized_partition
     36 def randomized_select(A, p, r, i):
     37     """Return the ith smallest element of the array A[p:r+1]
     38 
     39     Arguments:
   (...)
     43     i -- ordinal number for ith smallest
     44     """

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'randomized_quicksort'

I am stuck here.

There should be instructions, either in the textbook or there might be a README in Python.zip. They probably won't cover VSCode specifically, but they can at least point you in the right direction. Without those details, I don't think we can really answer this question, but if you do find them, please [edit] to add them.

"I do not see an "import project" option in VSC." - There isn't one. The closest equivalent is "Open folder". Although, there might be more setup required.

@wjandrea there are no instructions except this in the README "This folder contains Python implementations of the algorithms in Introduction to Algorithms, Fourth edition, by Thomas H. Cormen,..."

@wjandrea I had already tried "Open Folder". No benefit. BTW, someone has voted to close the question even though no one has answered!

Looking at the zip file, the randomized_partition module is in the Chapter 7 folder.  In order for it to work, you will also need the quicksort module in the Chapter 7 folder.
Put copies of all three files into the same folder, and then running python randomized_select.py, or using the debugger should work.
You may need to adjust your launch.json settings so that it uses the target script's directory as the working directory instead of the base folder of your workspace.
An alternative workflow would be to copy the functions out of the quicksort.py and randomized_partition.py files into randomized_select.py, and then you can remove the import statement entirely, as long as there are no function name conflicts.

"Put copies of all three files into the same folder". not practical to do it for all the examples.

@likejudo  As the authors of the book didn't see fit to provide you with proper modules, its one of the better options. You could get rid of the chapter folders entirely, and put all of the provided code in one folder.  Their readme also states the code might not actually match the pseudocode give in the book, as they "changed it where they saw fit".

After some more searching, I found that I have to create an environment variable PYTHONPATH to point to the folder that has the module - creating a 'custom module'. Unfortunately, I cannot just point to the root module, but must each time, edit the variable and append a new folder for each module, to the path.



You could consider a bash script to automatically loop through all of the subfolders, append them into a string, and export that to PYTHONPATH.

Looking into this found that

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'randomized_quicksort'

This means in the current folder where your randomized_select.py is present, the module you are trying to import isn’t present there. Try creating then importing the module. This may fix your issue.
To import a project in VS Code:

From File select Open Folder

Navigate to your folder you want to import


Always use and place import statement in the starting of the code i.e., very first.

"Try ... importing the module." ??? That's what they're trying to do!

Sir, i advice them to create the module first and then again try to import it. @wjandrea

What you said is "creating or importing". It seems like you meant "creating then importing".

Thankyou sir for correcting.
